# Configuration section encryption is not supported

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config, identity

I have encrypted the Identity section of my Web.config file using the below command.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef ContainerName C:\project -prov RsaProvider
```

Now when i run my website on the server after exporting my keys and importing them on the server it give me the below error.

```
Configuration section encryption is not supported
```

Any Idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be able to unencrypt the sytem.web/identity section you must have this entry as the last line of your  section.

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
```

Example:

```
<system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
        </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```